# How to compute the basis

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, linear-programming, computational-geometry

Given $n$ sets of linear constraints $\Theta_1, \cdots, \Theta_n$ which are over $\vec{x}_1, \cdots, \vec{x}_n$ respectively where $\vec{x}_i$ and $\vec{x}_j$ are pairwise disjoint, and 
 $W=
\begin{bmatrix}
w_1[\vec{x}_1]\\
\vdots\\
w_n[\vec{x}_n]\\
\end{bmatrix}$ 
where $w_i$ is an $m$-dim row vector  each entry of which is a  **linear function** over $\vec{x}_i$.  Given $d\in \mathbb{R}^m$, we define 
 $\max Wd= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\max_{\vec{x}_1 \in \Theta_1} w_1[\vec{x}_1] \cdot d\\
\vdots\\
\max_{\vec{x}_n \in \Theta_n} w_n[\vec{x}_n] \cdot d\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Clearly 
$A=\{\max Wd\mid d\in \mathbb{R}^m\}$ is *not* a linear space (see example below).

**The question is to compute a basis of the linear space spanned by $A$?**

Eample:
Let $W=[ x\  y]$ and $\Theta_1=\{0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1, x+y=1\}$. (In this case $n=1$ and $m=2$). Then

- for $d=[1\  0]^T$, we have $\max Wd= [1]$;
- for $d=[ 0\ 1]^T$, we have $\max Wd= [1]$;
- for $d=[1\ 1]^T$, we have $\max Wd= [1]$.

In this case $A=\mathbb{R}$.

The motivation of the problem is from geometry and an interesting feature here is that the optimization is involved which makes the problem unusual.